# Codeigniter: session tempdata is removed on session destroy

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I need to display some data on a page only for 20 minutes .for that purpose  i am using the tempdata in codeigniter

Actually the tempdata is a session data and i am mark it as a tempdata using `mark_as_temp` method

Here is my code

```
 public function final_result()
    {
    //make the session data as tempdata    
        $this->session->mark_as_temp(
          array('hotel_basic','user_ht_bk_data','hotel_info','hotel_search_query','booking_response','ht_star_rating','each_rooms'),1200       
        );     
      //after marking as tempdata destroy the original sessiondata
      $this->session->sess_destroy();
     //read from the tempdata
      $data['result']=$this->session->tempdata('user_ht_bk_data');

      $this->view('final-view',$data);
    }
```

But the `$data['result']` will returns null value.

As per codeigniter documentation  `sess_destroy()` never remove the tempdata.

But in my case the `tempdata` is removed when performing  session_destroy

Comment: which version do you use - in the current documentation stands : After the value expires, or the session expires or is deleted, the value is automatically removed. 
look @ : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#tempdata 
so if you destroy the session the value will be removed

Comment: @shammon Ah are you running PHP 7?

Answer (score 1):

> Once you use `sess_destroy()`, all session data (***including flashdata and tempdata***) will be **destroyed permanently and functions will be unusable during the same request** after you destroy the session.

[Destroying a Session In Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#destroying-a-session)

**Solutions**

1. Show final result as usual (without session destroy)  and make
   [countdown with JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/mrwilk/qVuHW/) to destroy session in 20 mints.
2. [Use cookies](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html)

Comment: @shammon check answer

Comment: @shammon happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

That is because the data to be set as tempdata must already exit in the session beforehand. As [stated in the documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#tempdata) you need to try something like:

```
$_SESSION['user_ht_bk_data'] = 'Test string'; // Or use set_tempdata with $this->session->set_tempdata('user_ht_bk_data', 'Test string', 300);
$this->session->mark_as_temp( 'user_ht_bk_data', 1200 ); // No need to use this if you used set_tempdata();
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$data['result']=$this->session->tempdata('user_ht_bk_data');
```

Comment: the same thing is  i am used only difference is one argument in `mark_as_temp` is an array

Comment: I don't see your code adding session data. Please post all relevant code, there might be something elsewhere having an impact.